# Making React.FC global in Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I already made React global in TS with:

```
import R from 'react';

declare global {
  const React: typeof R;
}
```

This makes TS understand built-in React methods. However, this doesn't seem to make React types global.

E.g. I want to make `React.FC` or `React.PropsWithChildren`, how can I do so?

Comment: This is a bad practice. Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: So I don't have to `import React from 'react'` in half my files

Comment: You have to do that anyway. Besides, all of those files depend on that import.

Comment: What do you mean? I'm using Webpack's ProvidePlugin so the React object is "global" already

Comment: That's also a bad practice. The point of a module system is to have explicit dependencies and fully scoped applications and libraries. The provide plug-in is for shimming dependencies that expect globals, like some jQuery plugins, this use is abusive.

Comment: It doesn't matter, it saves me time, the pros clearly outweigh the cons IMO. I'm still looking for a way to make `React.FC` global

Answer (score 2):

in `react-app-env.d.ts` or can use a `global.d.ts` add

```
declare type FC<P = {}> = React.FunctionComponent<P>;
```

this consist of using the keyword `declare` on types in a d.ts file, so the compiler will bring them into global scope

with this approach instead of using `React.FC` just use `FC`, neither bring react on scope if you are using react 17

then

```
import React from 'react'

export const Component: React.FC = ()=> {}
```

becomes

```
export const Component: FC = () => {}
```

after this you may need to restart ts server to apply the change

i understand why you do this, and i do not consider it a bad practice as @aluan-haddad commented, since you are only importing a type definition not a object, ***i support the idea that types should not be imported as long no other type have the same name, because type imports are not needed in the transpiled javascript***, it is the same approach that the majority of the libraries of DefinitelyTyped follows.

you can also bring your app business types to global scope using the same approach if their names don't overlap with others, remember this is only for making global type definitions, not global objects (in that case you can use something like singleton in typescript, or react context).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using React 16.14(?) or >=17.0 and typescript@>4.1=, https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html#whats-a-jsx-transform might be what you want. You don't have to do any d.ts shenaningans, it's just tweaking the tsconfig to change the JSX factory.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1/#jsx-factories

Comment: can you explain how this would enable to use the React.FC type definitions in global scope?

Comment: @AlonsoPalazuelos using the newer transform means there's no requirement to have the default export `import React from 'react'` at the top of files with JSX in them. Typescript will allow any func that return to a JSX.Element to be used in TSX. With or without a global declaration. My suggestion is to use the new transform, and not tweak the type to be global. I can count the number of times I've used React.FC explicity on one hand. Most of the time, tsc's type inference is good enough.

Comment: i understand there are some cases when React.FC typing is not needed, because if the function return JSX typescript will understand it as a react function, as you said however they may be cases when FC is useful for example when typing function parameters as the generic React.FC<A,B,C....> type